# What are the proper punctuations required in the stylistic phrasing: "from [location] to [location]; from [else] to [where]"?

Tags: phrases, punctuation

How do I properly punctuate this?

- I was abroad to accomplish these tasks – from Denver to Paris where my brother is, from Milan to Seoul to see my friends.

Comment: It's infelicitous. 'I was abroad to accomplish these tasks – journeying from Denver to Paris where my brother is, and then from Milan to Seoul to see my friends.' works. If you want to be more staccato, 'I was abroad to accomplish these tasks – journeying from Denver to Paris where my brother is; from Milan to Seoul to see my friends.' is a possibility. The comma feels too lightweight (though there's probably a rule somewhere saying that dashes and semicolons shouldn't be mixed, and another saying you can only use listing semicolons on Thursdays). But 'tasks' for journeys seems strange.

Comment: [correction: punctuation, no s.] Is "seeing friends" a "task"??  I think you need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: (1) skip _these_. (2) comma after _Paris_. (3) semicolon instead of comma after _is_. Both comma and semicolon indicate intonations (semicolon is a full stop), and those are the intonations that make sense of this.

Comment: I find the phrase "I was abroad" to be ambiguous and the context does not help to decide which. Abroad should thus to be avoided. Abroad - (i) adj./adv. in a foreign country *"He was abroad when his mother died." "I rarely go abroad for my holidays"* (ii) adv. widely; publicly *"The news that the company was in difficulties soon spread abroad."*

Comment: Can you provide more context? The punctuation is potentially ok (particularly if you're referring to previously mentioned tasks), but I'm not sure I get the meaning. The existing punctuation (or lack of it) conveys the sense of a whirlwind of movement, but doesn't explain the purpose of each journey. If you just want to list some of the places you were and some of the things you did while performing tasks that you enumerate elsewhere, fine; but if you're trying to be specific I would restructure (were your friends in Milan and Seoul, or for some reason did you start in Milan to go see them?).

Answer (score 1):

Without more context it's hard to tell what this sentence is trying to do. As mentioned, 'tasks' is probably not the right word for something like seeing friends.

In my mind the colon says you are about to talk about your tasks you were accomplishing (the direct object), but then in your list you lead with the places you were travelling to/from instead. So there's a misalignment of focus that is making the sentence sound off.

Some ideas:

- "I was abroad to accomplish these tasks: Meet up with* my brother (Denver to Paris), and see my friends (from Milan to Seoul)."
- "I was accomplishing tasks while abroad: In Paris (leaving from Denver) I met with* my brother, and in Seoul (leaving from Milan) I saw friends."

*insert your own verb

On its own I don't think punctuation is going to perfect this sentence.